# Java: select serial port to read Arduino Uno

Tags: java, serial-port, arduino, rfid, rxtx

I am trying to read from an [RFID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio-frequency_identification) tag number that is scanned by a parallax RFID reader and sent to the computer using the Arduino device. I am trying to read from the serial port using `RXTXCommDrive`, but the problem is that when the Arduino is connected to a PC it is connected to [COM3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COM_%28hardware_interface%29) and when connected to a laptop it is connected to COM4. Is there way to loop through the COM ports and find the correct port?

Answer (score 1):

The RXTX wiki lists two examples for listing available ports:

- http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Discovering_comm_ports
- http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Discovering_available_comm_ports

But: What do you do if you find two ports? So either you should use some configuration file anyway.

A third possibility would be: Most USB drivers allow assignment of specific chips to a specific COM port id. For Arduinos using the FT232R chip there are two ways: Reassign the port ID via the driver settings *OR* reassign a bunch of port IDs via registry edits.

The relevant Application Notes can be found here:

http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/AppNotes.htm

- **AN_107**   "*Advanced Driver Options*"
- **AN_132**   "*Re-Assigning COM Port Numbers Using the Windows Registry*"

I'm sure the other chips of newer Arduinos have similar capabilities.